# What is adobe illustrator CC outline view showing me? Outline conflicts with preview

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, outline

In adobe illustrator CC 2019 When I collect my illustration for export as a PDF there is a lot of blank space collected with my design.  My design contains vector elements and png content.
When I view in outline mode it is clear that illustrator thinks that my content is larger than it is, but in preview mode the selection box indicates that I am only selecting my desired content.

What is outline mode showing me?
Why does it appear to conflict with preview mode?
How can I select only my desired content?
A screenshot of the outline view is below, along with an annotated version.  Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Raster data such as "*png content*" is not clipped or removed in the "skeleton" of an Illustrator file.

Raster content may be *visually* clipped for the preview. However, in outline mode, when viewing the construction of the file or its skeleton, raster bounding boxes, which are *always* a rectangles, will be visible.

If you wish outline mode to precisely match preview mode, don't use raster images.

Note that the use of raster images within Illustrator is **not** inherently a problem.

Comment: I had cropped the png content after importing into illustrator.  Is there a way to make the bounding box match the cropped area?  Thanks.

Comment: **How** did you "crop" the image? If you used teh crop feature in AI, which embeds the raster image, then they bounding box *should* match the preview area.

Comment: Also, I don't think I need preview to match outline, I just don't want the extra white-space included when I export my design as a PDF.  Not using raster content is not an option for me, the content that I need to use only exists in raster form.

Comment: Realize that all I've seen appears to be outline mode.. so I have no clue what is extra and what is not.. I can only base any answer upon your provided screenshots. It is entirely possible the "extra areas" you point out may be due to something else, such as an effect. Without direct file examination, it's all merely "best guess".

Comment: I'm using Illustrator CC 2019, I'm on the most recent available update.